# Strings with double quotes in html input field displaying as &quot

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

Im getting data from sql and using php to generate javascript for an edit button for each entry. The edit interface uses a text input in a form. When the generated edit button is clicked, the text within this field is set to equal the name of the entry from sql.

This works fine in all cases expect when the name contains double quotes ("), in which case the quotes are replaced with &quot in the text field.

The php genertaed javascript is below:

```
function editButton($suffix,$name)
{   
    echo "<button class=\"edit\" onclick=\"editMode$suffix()\">Edit</button>";
    echo "<script>
            <!-- 
            function editMode$suffix(){
                document.getElementById(\"title\").innerHTML = \"Edit Artist\"
                var main = document.getElementById(\"main\");

                main.style.display = 'none';

                var edit = document.getElementById(\"edit\");
                edit.style.display = 'block';     

                //Set the input of the edit interface to be equal to the current name
                document.getElementById(\"editInput\").value = \"$name\";
                document.getElementById(\"artEdit\").value = \"$name\";
            }       
            -->
        </script>"; 
}
```

The $name variable is sanitized via htmlentities() before being passed to the function. Without doing so, the edit interface for entries with quotes will not even display.

I found this which sounds like the same issue but no solutions (https://code.google.com/archive/p/embeddedjavascript/issues/19) :/

IF anyone has a solution or can point out some stupid thing im doing thats causing this it would be very appreciated. At this point im going to have to just disable database entry for double quotes and limit to singles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change all the double-quotes in the JavaScript portion to single-quotes, then use [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) on the `$name` variable:

```
function editButton($suffix, $name)
{
    $name = addslashes( html_entity_decode($name) );
    echo "<button class='edit' onclick='editMode$suffix()'>Edit</button>";
    echo "<script>
        <!-- 
        function editMode$suffix() {
            document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'Edit Artist'
            var main = document.getElementById('main');

            main.style.display = 'none';

            var edit = document.getElementById('edit');
            edit.style.display = 'block';     

            //Set the input of the edit interface to be equal to the current name
            document.getElementById('editInput').value = '$name';
            document.getElementById('artEdit').value = '$name';
        }       
        -->
    </script>"; 
}
```

*Also added [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to converts the entities back to their initial state. Consider removing the `htmlentities()` altogether, in which case, you can remove the `html_entity_decode()` from the above script.

Comment: Awesome thank you you're a life saver. Id tried just switching over to single quotes but wasn't aware of the addslashes function, very useful. Weird thing is i tried using str_replace to do the same but didnt get anywhere .